# From an Android chooser is there a way to select more than 73 images from Google Photos without getting a RESULT_CANCELLED return code?

Tags: java, android, google-photos

I have created an Android app that presents a button to add images to a gallery. Images can be selected from compatible `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` providers. When selecting images from the Google Photos provider, it works fine when selecting up to 73 images. When selecting 74+ images, it immediately (no image downloads are attempted) returns to my app and the Activity result code is `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`.

Code to open the image chooser:

```
...
    someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ChooserActivityResult(this,
                        this.getBaseContext()));
...    
    /**
     * Open image chooser.
     */
    public void openImageChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.intent_chooser_select_images)));
    }
```

`ChooserActivityResult`:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {

        HashSet<Uri> sources = new HashSet<>();
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            //do stuff with the Uri(s)
        }
    }
```

**Selecting 74 or more images from Google Photos returns:** `ActivityResult{resultCode=RESULT_CANCELED, data=null}`

Selecting 73 or fewer images returns successfully (after downloading the necessary images) and I can process the `Uri` for one item, or `ClipData`  for multiple items.

Selecting any number of images from local storage (not Google Photos) returns successfully and I can process the `Uri` for one item, or `ClipData`  for multiple items.

Also of note, my App can process an incoming share intent. Via this method, it is able to receive up to 200 images from a Google Photos-initiated share (Google Photos only allows up to 200 images to be shared at a time).

Troubleshooting:

- My app does not throw any exceptions. It recognizes the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED` result code and does nothing (as it should).
- Watching logcat, there are no messages obviously related to Google Photos when it simply ends and returns to my app.
- Device: Google Pixel 6a (tried with both debug and release variants)

I appreciate any pointers. It's possible Google Photos has some silent limit on the number of images that can be returned via the chooser. That would be unfortunate.

UPDATE 2022-10-24:

Simple app to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/cedarrapidsboy/google_photos_chooser_example

UPDATE 2022-10-25:

Google bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/255485457

Comment: "It's possible Google Photos has some silent limit on the number of images that can be returned via the chooser" -- my guess is that it's a bug in the Google Photos app.

Comment: `Selecting 73 or fewer images returns successfully (after downloading the necessary images) ` What do you mean? What should be downloaded? If the user selects that much images you get that much urls in clipdata of onactivity result. There is no download. Images necessary? For what?

Comment: Did you try devices with different Android versions?

Comment: @blackapps, how Google Photos works in this chooser is that when you select one or more images and press "Done", it pops-up a progress bar showing status of downloading the selections before returning to the calling app. If my selection is 74+ items, the progress bar doesn't show and control is returned to my app with nothing to process.

Comment: Where does it download from if the selected images are on your device? And where does it download to before returning?

Comment: @blackapps , I can reproduce the issue on a Pixel 6a running Android 13 and an emulator running Android 12.
The downloading step seems to be internal to Google Photos. I assume it is downloading the images to a local cache before presenting them to the calling app. The same downloading progress bar appears when ***sharing*** multiple photos from Google Photos to my app. For instance, if I select 200 images, and then share them, Google Photos will first pre-download them before I can select my app in the share menu.

Comment: Re: "Where does it download from if the selected images are on your device?" -- also want to clarify that this same behavior occurs whether or not the Google Photos images have already been _cached_ on the device. With 73 images, if they have already previously been selected (e.g., I've tried this before), the progress bar still appears that says "downloading n of 73", but it goes **really** fast. It goes slower if the files had never been tried before. At 74 images, the progress bar just doesn't happen and returns to the app with a null data set.

Comment: Updated the question to include sample Github repo (Android app) that reproduces the issue.